# What Coldfusion Error LogFile Analysis tools are available?

Tags: coldfusion, analysis, error-reporting

As part of my attempt to role my own coldfusion framework for my company, I want to see what kind of tools that can summarize top user/server errors based on the log files...

We have given up on trying to have a server monitor, and i have tried several debugging templates, but right now, seems we want a solution that helps us identify key problem areas on production/development, without adding additional performance loading issues to the servers..

So do you know of any free, open-source, or even commercial solutions to analyze coldfusion 8 log files, and create a summary indicating top user and server errors?

Thanks..

Comment: I am trying to find a tool to analyze log files, then find a way to zip them from production to dev.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know anything specific to ColdFusion, but there are lots of log parsers out there can can be configured for coldfusion (in the end it just uses Log4J anyway).

Lots of people like Apache Chainsaw:
http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html
It's free obviously. and built for Log4j

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own, it's not hard really.  the log files are in plain text so parsing the information is pretty simple.  I've made a basic mail log reader when I needed an easy way to see if mail from an application was being sent.

Lucky for you it looks like someone already did it.  You may be able to use it out of the box or you may have to tweek it a bit but the code is all there.

http://jehiah.cz/archive/coldfusion-error-log-viewer

The comments in the blog also point to a product, cfmxtrace.
http://www.vanzwijndregt.com/trace/cfmxtrace.html